# How to talk with your teenage son when he caught you having sex with your partner?

Tags: teen, age-appropriate, communication, sex

My husband and I got caught by my teenager son having oral sex. I am embarrassed and I don't know how to handle it. Can you give me any advise?

Answer (score 13):

I'd let him bring it up.  I walked in on my parents *in flagrante delicto* when I was 8, and RAN out of the room and hid in the office for a while.  My dad, bless his heart, came to find me and assure me everything was fine.  "I know what you guys were doing, Daddy!  I'm not scared, just freaked out!  Leave me alone!"  He left, and I vowed then and there to NEVER EVER IN THE HISTORY OF EVER to open their door without knocking first.

Problem solved. Crisis averted.  And my psyche repaired itself just fine.  (But the mind wipe has never been completely successful.)

Comment: This literally made me LOL. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Hopefully you've already had the 'big talk' if your son is already a teenager. If not, now is the perfect time to bring up the topic and get talking.

If you already had the talk, then he's likely as embarrassed as you are and perhaps the conversation has to be less about sex and more about how to knock on doors before entering.